(Why) Is TMS really needed to reference NMR spectra?
In NMR textbooks it is oftentimes stated that referencing NMR spectra to an internal standard such as tetramethylsilane (TMS) is necessary to make spectra comparable as the absolute resonance frequencies obtained are dependent on the magnetic field strength and thus on the NMR machine/magnet used for measurements.
However, this chain of causality doesn't make much sense to me as the resulting relative values (meaning the difference in resonance frequency between sample and reference signal) are equally dependent on the magnetic field strength. This is why for calculating the chemical shift, the relative value is divided by the magnetic field strength of the NMR machine so that you eventually truly get a value that is independent of the field strenght and thus allows comparability.
My question here is what the use of TMS (or any comparable internal reference) is then good for at all? If referencing to an internal standard is truly just about allowing comparability between spectra obtained from different field strengths wouldn't it be sufficient to just normalize the obtained absolute resonance frequencies to the used magnetic field strength without using any reference compound (please see image linked below)? Is there any other reason why the use of an internal reference is really needed that I'm missing?


For future reference: don't link to illustrations, embed them directly. And provide a note to credit the source.

I'm no NMR expert, but I wonder if the precision with which the field strength, and thus the Larmour frequencies of various protons, are known is much less than the precision of the chemical shift.  If a magnet had B = 14.11 T instead of 14.1 as assumed, then all the shifts would be off some, right?

The difference is not divided by the field strength per se, but by the resonance frequency of TMS - this is what makes the chemical shift field-independent.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/47913/why-is-tetramethylsilane-tms-used-as-an-internal-standard-in-nmr-spectroscopy

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/158511/two-different-definitions-for-chemical-shift-nmr

Short version: In addition to establish a good reference frequency for the then device independent $\delta$ scale, because of all protons in TMS are magnetically equivalent to yield a strong, easy identifiable signal, it equally is a good reference for lock and shim of the spectrometer, i.e. to monitor and correct the field strength and field homogeneity during the experiment.  The two later quality checks typically run automatically in the background with little intervention by the routine user.
Longer version: No, you don't need specifically TMS as an internal reference to record the NMR spectrum. (See for instance papers by the Hoye group about no-D NMR spectroscopy.) You equally can use an other internal reference, for instance $\ce{D2O}$ or other deuterated liquids, or trifluoro acetic acid (filled in a capillary, then immersed into the NMR tube to record the sample's and the reference's signals simultaneously). Or indeed, you use an external electronic reference signal; however its position (frequency) can drift over time - both unintentional and unnoticed - during experiments.  Depending on the local setup (e.g., conventional probe head vs. cryogenic probe) and experimental protocol and sample (e.g., $\ce{^{31}P}$ vs $\ce{^{15}N}$ NMR), some of them may require hours to complete.
TMS in particular became a popular reference in $\ce{^1H}$- and $\ce{^{13}C}$-NMR spectroscopy because

it is an affordable chemical
signals of this reference show up where typical sample signals are absent
not only is the pattern of TMS easy to identify by position, but equally by multiplicity. In the case of TMS, all 12 protons are magnetically equivalent and yield a singulet in 1H-NMR spectroscopy. Hence only a little of this substance has to be added as internal reference.
contrasting to e.g., $\ce{D2O}$, this one substance can serve as reference both for $\ce{^1H}$ and $\ce{^{13}C}$ (as well as 2D correlation spectra of the two).
in many branches of synthesis, $\ce{^1H}$, $\ce{^{13}C}$, and correlation NMR spectra of $\ce{^1H}$ and $\ce{^{13}C}$ fulfill the needs of the chemists (there are many more than COSY, HSQC, HMBC, ...).  If not (e.g., an additional brief $\ce{^{31}P}$ NMR experiment) the signal of TMS can be used to electronically reference the $\ce{^{31}P}$ trace, too, though the better way is to use an internal reference proper like triphenylphosphine.
typically, it doesn't react with your sample, solutes well enough in typical organic solvents (it is added to e.g., $\ce{CDCl3}$ - if you want it added) and still is easily removed by distillation after the experiment


(1) Hoye, T. R.; Eklov, B. M.; Ryba, T. D.; Voloshin, M.; Yao, L. J. No-D NMR (No-Deuterium Proton NMR) Spectroscopy: A Simple Yet Powerful Method for Analyzing Reaction and Reagent Solutions. Org. Lett. 2004, 6 (6), 953–956. https://doi.org/10.1021/ol049979+.
(2) Hoye, T. R.; Eklov, B. M.; Voloshin, M. No-D NMR Spectroscopy as a Convenient Method for Titering Organolithium (RLi), RMgX, and LDA Solutions. Org. Lett. 2004, 6 (15), 2567–2570. https://doi.org/10.1021/ol049145r.
